# How to get the Windows Vista operating system key? I would like to re-install the OS again.

Tags: windows, licensing

I would like to re-install the Windows Vista again? Where can I get the key for the system on which it is installed? The key on the back of my system is fudged beyond recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't get the *same* key back as the one behind your computer (it's not necessarily the same as the one it is using right now), but to get back the current one, you can use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy/download).